# Cluster of dokku nodes running Elixir/Phoenix

Tags: cluster-computing, phoenix-framework, dokku

How can I configure a bunch of dokku nodes (I use the DigitalOcean One-Click Droplets) running an Elixir/Phoenix system to work as a cluster. I found an article describing Elixir clusters in general (https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/01/28/running-elixir-and-phoenix-projects-on-a-cluster-of-nodes) but I do not know how to apply this to dokku.

Comment: this resource is really good in explaining the process. http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/how-to-set-up-an-elixir-cluster-on-amazon-ec2/

Comment: Yeah I saw that and it's really good. And by now I think that dokku is not the way to go. Hmmmm decisions decisions ...

Comment: Honestly, I'd agree with you. Im not the biggest fan of the PAAS approach with elixir/phoenix. Setting something up with edeliver is super easy and results in an one line command hot upgrade. If you need some help let me know and I can run you through it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dokku Maintainer here: We might not be the best fit for your use case. We're a platform optimized for single-server solutions. While this doesn't mean that you *couldn't* do multi-server, I believe that Elixer requires direct tcp - not http - access in order to setup clustering. You could get around this by implementing a custom proxy plugin on top of haproxy instead of nginx.

If you have a simpler solution, I would always go with that :)